# Writing SQL query to get percentage having certain word/total count of rows in table

Tags: sql

I have a table as shown below. I want to return promo % value which is `[count of rows having promos value]/[total count of rows]`. For ex. below will be 80% [4/5].

| Type | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Promo | 7 |
| Promo | 17 |
| Promo | 87 |
| Non-Promo | 127 |
| Promo | 778 |

I tried using subquery but not able to get the expected value

Comment: Use a `case` _expression_ to do _conditional aggregation_.

Comment: mysql and ms sql server are two different database products with different implementations of sql. Which one do you actually use?

Comment: *"I tried using subquery but not able to get the expected value"* And what was that attempt? You were told, when posting your question, the following: *"Not all questions benefit from including code, but if your problem is better understood with code you’ve written, you should include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)."* Knowing your attempt(s) will most certainly help us help you here, as we can then explain where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Type = 'Promo' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END)/COUNT(*) AS PROMO_PERCENTAGE
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: Depending on the database, you may get integer arithmetic; always returning 0 for anything other than 100%.  Better to use `1.0 ELSE 0.0`

Comment: good point! Thanks for your addition

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```sql
SELECT 100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN Type = 'Promo' THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) AS pct
FROM yourTable;
```